# Center of mass and moments

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

I got part $(i)$,  but got stuck on part $(ii)$.

For part two, I know that I have to take the moments about the center of the base of the cylinder (let's call that $\text{O}$)
I know that the center of mass of the cone is $\frac{1}{4}^{\text{th}}$ the height from it's base. And I know that the center of mass of the cylinder is in the middle.

Let's call the height of the cylinder $x$.

Now I have to find the moment of the weight of the cone and cylinder about $\text{O}$. And equate it to the moment of the entire solid. I don't know how to find the distance of the center of mass of the entire solid From $\text{O}$.

The marking scheme of the paper says that the distance $$OG = 0.4 \tan(70^{\circ})$$

(where G is the point where the center of mass of the entire solid lies and O is the center of the base of the cylinder.) 
Also, if you have any sources for CIE A level mechanics $2$, could you please give me a link to it, I have very less resources as I am doing my A levels all by myself at home.

Answer (score 1):

Do a sketch that includes the *combined* center of mass in order to solve this problem. If the line of action of gravity (through the center of mass) goes through the base, then the system is stable.

So find the distance indicated below, and if it is zero, then that is the maximum height of the center of mass, and hence the maximum height of the cone.

[image: sketch]

Comment: What you are saying is true if you are talking about the center of mass (CM) of the entire structure (combination of cylinder and cone).  (Your drawing looks like it is only the CM of the cone, 1/4 the height from the base). You need to include the CM of the cylinder as its counter clockwise moment will counteract that of the cone until the sum of the moments is zero.

Comment: @BobD - To clarify I edited the answer adding the word "combined center of mass". I am treating the system as if it was a single body. On the other hand, friction does add a complication here as it might be possible for the cone to tip away from the base while the base remains on the slope. I see now my answer does not go into the depth needed to answer the question.

Comment: I kind of figured that's what you meant, but just wanted to make sure. I'v up voted your edited answer.The problem can be solved with the combined CM per your approach, or the CMs of the individual parts per my approach. The effect of friction on tipping is a complication normally ignored with these problems. The real problem with the OP approach was taking moments around the wrong point, which both of us have shown.

Answer (score 0):

***For part two, I know that I have to take the moments about the center of the base of the cylinder***

No. You have to take the sum of the moments about point A as indicated in the figure below. That is the point where potential tipping occurs and is where the sum of the moments equals zero at the verge of tipping. A net clockwise moment about A will cause tipping.

The CM of the cone will always be higher than that of the cylinder. As the cylinder height increases the height of the CM of the cylinder and cone increases. Eventually, the CM of the cone will start to contribute a clockwise moment about A.  As long as the counter clockwise moment due to the CM of the cylinder is greater than the clockwise moment of the cone, the structure remains stable.  But at some point the height of the cylinder will result in the sum of the moments about A being zero. That’s when tipping is impending. Any further increase will result in a net clockwise moment and tipping.

From here, you should be able to do the necessary caclulations.

Hope this helps

[image]